# what are .rbin extension files in R

Tags: r

I am new to R programming language. I am downloading some scientific data which are archived in zip. On unzipping, it gives out some files having .rbin extension which are actually binary files. While on googling the term ".rbin" i am unable to find the way to use them. Can anybody show me a guide on how to use these .rbin files?

Comment: My guess is that these are saved sessions, which you might be able to open using `load()`. My googling points to the [sessionTools package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sessionTools/sessionTools.pdf)

Comment: If you can't ask the people who supply the data, you could at least tell us where you got it from. Then we might get one ourselves and have a chance of figuring it out. File extensions do not have to relate to the file format at all. You can't send someone a jpeg by renaming a png.

Comment: Thanks Andrie and spacedman... The link for the data is https://synapse.sagebase.org . Well it requires login to access the data. I would try to figure out it by the suggestions provided by all of you.

Comment: File extensions are no guarantee of anything, trust no one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension `rbin` is to my knowledge not an established convention like e.g. `.Rdata` or `.rda`. I assume that you are right, and that they are binary files. To read binary files, you need to use the `readBin` function. To get good results, you do need to find out some details:

- What is the size of the stored binary numbers, e.g. 4 bytes.
- What is stored, e.g. logical, numeric, double, integer, etc.
- If integers are stored, are they unsigned or not.
- Is the file stored with big or little endianess.

Please take a look at `?readBin` for more details.

Alternatively, the `rbin` file could contain a binary representation of R objects (as @Andrie commented). In this case you need to use the `load` function to load the objects into your workspace, see `?load` for more details.

Comment: Yes, It is getting loaded by using the load function. Thanks Paul Hiesmtra . If i encounter something strange further , i would let you know.

Comment: It would be helpful if you accept my answer to show to everyone else that this question was solved. In addition, it gets me some reputation for my trouble...and if you have a new question, please ask a new one and do not edit this one.